# Awk value greater than 40

Tags: awk, grep

Can someone please help me. I'm trying to get values greater than 40, but when it's at 100 it doesn't get it.

```
[root@localhost home]# df -Pk --block-size=1M

Filesystem            1048576-blocks  Used Available Capacity Mounted on

/dev/mapper/rhel-root          22510 13135      9375      59% /

devtmpfs                         905     0       905       0% /dev

tmpfs                            920     1       920       1% /dev/shm

tmpfs                            920     9       911       1% /run

tmpfs                            920     0       920       0% /sys/fs/cgroup

/dev/sda1                       1014   178       837      18% /boot

Linux_DB2                     240879 96794    144086      41% /media/sf_Linux_DB2

tmpfs                            184     1       184       1% /run/user/42

tmpfs                            184     1       184       1% /run/user/0

*/dev/sr0                          56    56         0     100% /run/media/root/VBox_GAs_5.2.20*

[root@localhost home]# df -Pk --block-size=1M | awk '$5 > 40'

Filesystem            1048576-blocks  Used Available Capacity Mounted on

/dev/mapper/rhel-root          22510 13135      9375      59% /

Linux_DB2                     240879 96794    144086      41% /media/sf_Linux_DB2
```

The */dev/sr0                          56    56         0     100% /run/media/root/VBox_GAs_5.2.20* doesn't come out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following once.

```
df -hP | awk '$5+0>40'
```

***Explanation:*** Since 5th field of disk usage is having string with digits added, so by adding a zero `+0` with `$5` it tells `awk` to keep only digits in comparison and it will NOT have strings in it. Then this condition will considered like digits are getting compared, will show the right output then. Here `-P` option with `df` command is also crucial since it gives the output of `df` in a single line and it makes `awk` command's life easy to get its calculations done.

Comment: OMG! It worked. Can you please explain what the +0 is for?

Comment: Ravinder, a simpler explanation simply would have been "+0 will force awk to treat it as a number rather than a string" :-) But good answer anyway.

Comment: Sorry, Ravinder, it *was* me, but unintentional. It's back now :-)